# Multiple form in the same ctp file with same controller in cakephp 3

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have an issue with a 2 different forms in one ctp file.
**explanation** : I want to use two forms related to different actions in same controller. I use the first form to add 2 text field a table and I use the second form just to search and retrieve the data.

MY ctp:

***Form 1 adding message and Email***

```
<?= $this->Form->create($message) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
    <input name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email</label>
    <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" type="email">
</div>
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]); 
$this->Form->end() ?>
```

***Form 2 Searching field :***

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['action' => 'search']]) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="what" class="col-form-label">What?</label>
    <input name="what" class="form-control" id="what" placeholder="What are you looking for?" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('country_id', [
        'options' => $countries,
        'id' => 'country_id',
        'label' => ['text' => __('Where?')]
    ]); ?>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary width-100">Search</button>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

So  i clicked on submit it works fine but when I clicked on search it doesn't go to the desired action it is still in the same action . Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This code is not doing what you think it's doing:

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]); 
$this->Form->end() ?>
```

It will echo the submit button but NOT the form end tag. You then open another form, but the browser may interpret this as a bad tag and ignore it. (Technically, I think the browser behaviour towards this malformed HTML is undefined, so you might get different behaviour from different browsers.)

Try this instead:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]); 
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

or

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]); 
echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

or

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]) .
$this->Form->end() ?>
```

I'd recommend the first option as being much clearer code and less prone to accidental breakage with future edits; I would never allow either of the latter two on a project I was managing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by replacing this code:

```
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]); 
$this->Form->end() ?>
```

By this  :

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class'=> "btn btn-primary large icon float-right"]); 
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Comment: The general way of indicating that my answer resolved the problem for you is to accept my answer.

Comment: P.S. Still think that, for clarity, it's better if you replace `<?=` with `<?php echo`.